# Generator for a shrinking list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I've just started to programm in python and really like the concept of generators.

So I've got a list of dictionaries and each dictionary consists of an id and a status, e.g. the first two elements could look like this

```
 lst =[{ "id":1, "status": "new"}, {"id": 2, "status"="finished"}]
```

The actual list can contain up to 10 items. Each id corresponds to a job and typically the order in which the jobs are finished is random.

I want to check if a job is finished and if so process it. If it is not finished, (due to the randomness) I want to check another job until all jobs are finished (typically they will be at some time)

So to me it sounds like a good use for generators, particularly in a pipeline (even though the efficency might not be important here).

```
def gener(lst):
    while lst:
    for item in lst:
        if item["status"] == "finished":
            yield lst.pop(list.index(item))  
        else:
            check_and_update_status(item)
```

The check and update function could look like this:

```
def check_and_update_status(item):
    item["status"]=finished
```

So my 1st question is: Is this an approach that makes sense? Or is a generator a bad choice here.

So, hopefully I can add these two question here:

2. Sometimes in the list there might be dictionaries without a status key. In that case, I want to perform the task in the else branch. How can I achieve this? Exception Handling?
3. In some literature on python/programming I learned that settings and programms shall be divided. So I'm wondering if I should hardcode  "finished" (and maybe also "status") here. The term "finished" stems from an external file and might be changed at some point in the future. Is there an elegant way to cirumvent this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mutating a `list` during iteration is unsafe and generally not well supported. Even if it worked, doing it with `lst.pop(lst.index(item))` is silly when you could just do `for i, item in enumerate(lst):` so you'd have the index available for free. One approach you could take is to avoid deleting while you iterate, simply storing the indices to delete, and using list comprehension to regenerate `lst` at the end.  For example:

```
while lst:
    todel = set()
    for i, item in enumerate(lst):
        if item["status"] == "finished":
            todel.add(i)
            yield item  
        else:
            check_and_update_status(item)
    if todel:
        lst = [x for i, x in enumerate(lst) if i not in todel]
```

Other approaches might work better if you had larger lists and more frequent removal from the list, but this approach optimizes for infrequent deletion without signing up for dangerous mutation while iterating side-effects.

For handling non-existent `"status"` keys, you can use `item.get("status")` instead of indexing syntax to avoid throwing an exception (with one argument, `get` returns `None` if the key does not exist, or you can pass a second argument to use as a default). Alternatively, to get the existing value if it exists, and set and get a default status if it does not yet exist, use `item.setdefault("status", "new")` (where `"new"` should be your default starting status).

So for example, to check and set, you'd use:

```
if item.setdefault("status", "new") == "finished":
```

Question 3 is hard to answer in the general case; if you have a proper schema for the data it's a good idea to use it rather than hard-coding in magic strings, but that's going to depend on your use case.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer. I like the idea with iterating also over the index. Not safe just means: don't do it, right? @question3: I think with the setdefault method I can easily use my data from the config file. So, at least for my case, you also answered question 3

Comment: Not safe means "Don't do it" (because it can raise exceptions or return invalid results if the mutation alters the list in an way that invalidates the iterator).

Comment: In an example I considered (status as int >=0, finished <=> status =0, and the  update functions just uses finished -=1) everything works, even what happens after deletion during iteration is in some way predictable. From what I observed, after deletion of an element the range of the indexes also decreases and eventually the iteration simply stops. So what bad things can exactly happen here? Do you have an example where an exception is raised or where the result is invalid?